# Amazon S3 Redirect Rule - Preserve Query Params

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, react-router

I noticed [Amazon S3 Redirect rule - GET data is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993675/amazon-s3-redirect-rule-get-data-is-missing) but after following the accepted answer my query params still are not being preserved.

I have a site that uses React and React Router, meaning I have several URLs that load identical HTML and JS and then the JS figures out which part of the app to load based on the URL.

For example:

/foo, /bar, /baz all should load index.html, which loads bundle.js. Then bundle.js observes the URL and routes to some React component (also in bundle.js).

However no foo, bar, or baz file exists in S3, only index.html. What I want to do is when I get a 404, redirect to /#!/{URL} (eg. /foo redirects to /#!/foo). This works fine with my redirect rule (below). However, I also want to bring query params with me (eg. /foo?ping=pong redirects to /#!/foo?ping=pong) but instead /foo?ping=pong just redirects to /#!/foo.

Here are my redirect rules:

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <Protocol>http</Protocol>
            <HostName>www.mydomain.com</HostName>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>#!/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Any ideas on some way I can achieve this? Ideally without having to go change something in S3/CloudFront every time I add a new page?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `/foo/?ping=pong` work as expected? (adding a trailing slash before the `?`)

Comment: Cross post... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751301/how-can-i-get-query-strings-in-my-amazon-s3-static-website

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The problem was that I had the origin set up in CloudFront not to forward Query Strings so when S3 got the request it would redirect properly without the query params. You can find this setting in CloudFront > Behaviors > Forward Query Strings.

Comment: Yes!! Lifesaver!

Comment: @doublejosh: You mean just hitting up S3 directly? Query params shouldn't be ignored then. In my case, CloudFront was removing query params, that was my problem. If you aren't using CloudFront, you shouldn't be experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Query params seem to be stripped with just S3 folder redirects, eg: `/my-page?this=that` >>> `/my-page/`

Comment: Any luck @doublejosh? Having the same issue.

Comment: Not able to find a solution to that other than being super careful are always sharing URLs with a final slash before the question mark.

Comment: For anyone looking for details on this, it's currently CloudFront Distributions > [click distribution] > Behaviors > [check behavior] > Edit > Cache Policy -> Create New Policy > Query strings > [select All]. Save. Save. Save.

Comment: @doublejosh The issue could be solved with edge function of CloudFront, please refer to the code block in https://juejin.cn/post/7254853023289491516 (the post is in Chinese)

Answer (score 5):

The menus and options in CloudFront/S3 change a lot over time.

Here is a December 2021 solution.

### Step 1) Create a "Request" Policy in CloudFront that allows QueryStrings

[image]

Note: you might want to also add some Headers like `Origin` or `Access-Control-`... headers for CORS.

### Step 2) Go to your Distribution > Update the Origin request policy

[image]

### Step 3) Kick a new Invalidation on `/*`

[image]

---

### Additional Notes for Debuging/Testing

1. I would recommend testing with `curl` in terminal rather than a browser to avoid caching and also seeing the details.  I do `curl -v https://example.com/cb?foo=bar1`.
2. Keep increasing the value of the query string (`bar1` in the above example, to `bar2`, `bar3`) with every test to make such there is no caching again.

Comment: I'm confused with the answers here. Should we be making a cache policy or a request policy?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have clear urls though you can also check out [this trick](http://aserafin.pl/2016/03/23/react-router-on-amazon-s3/). You need to setup cloudfront distribution and then alter 404 behaviour in "Error Pages" section of your distribution. That way you can again `domain.com/foo/bar` links :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I tried setting this up in cloudfront but when I look at the sources tab in Chrome inspector, is is loading the index.html page as my bundle.js file and so I'm getting an `unexpected token <` error. 

My website urls are of the from `https://mydomain.io/search/0.1/index.html/article/uuid. And in react router I have a basename of `search/0.1/index.html' so one of the route definitions is for `article/:id`.

S3 still seems to be looking for the folder `/search/0.1/index.html/article`. 

Any ideas how I can solve this issue?