# Keep query strings with AWS Amplify Hosting - React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, react-router, aws-amplify

I currently have a react app using `react-router-dom` that works locally but not when deployed using [AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/deploy-react-app-cicd-amplify/).

The problem is that when I route to a URL and use query strings, the browser gets a redirect and drops the query strings.

For example when I route to `/path?value1=foo&value2=bar`, the browser gets a 301 and redirects to url: `/0000000X/path/` as shown below

[image]

I have tried using hash values as well as the `/path/?value1=foo&value2=bar` approach as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751301/how-can-i-get-query-strings-in-my-amazon-s3-static-website) with no luck.

Below is my implementation:

***Button.js***

`href: '/path?value1=foo&value2=bar'`

***Path.js***

```
import queryString from 'query-string'
const values = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)
console.log(values.value1) 
console.log(values.value2)
```

***Routes.js***

```
 <AuthenticatedRoute path="/path" exact component={Path} props={childProps} />
```

All of this works fine locally, redirects and I can access the query string params, but not in S3. Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 8):

Add this to AWS Amplify's Rewrites and Redirect:

```
[
    {
        "source": "</^((?!\\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf)$).)*$/>",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "200",
        "condition": null
    },
    {
        "source": "/<*>",
        "target": "/",
        "status": "404",
        "condition": null
    }
]
```

Comment: i mistakenly down voted this answer while this answer is correct and works for me. now i can't upvote it unless the answer is edited. shouldn't i be able to upvote this ?

Comment: This solution worked for me, as did the one on [the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa) `[{"condition":null,"source":"</^[^.]+$|\\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>","status":"200","target":"/index.html"}]`. It even avoids getting a 404 at all. Unfortunately we still need to hard-code these url extensions.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was caused by the default www redirect: `https://example.com -> https://www.example.com`. And the solution was to use `www.`.

I think it's also possible to set up the www redirect correctly, see: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/97